# What means imaginary and real parts of the optical Hall conductivity?

Tags: quantum-optics, quantum-hall-effect

What is the meaning of the real and imaginary parts of the optical Hall conductivity and also the interpretation of the negative Hall conductivity?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking Are you thinking of the Faraday and Kerr effects in the QHE?  In thos cases the imaginary numbers refer to phase shifts and the rotations in the plane of polarization. In other optical contexts the imaginary parts describe absorbtion.

Comment: Thank you for your response. No, I'm not looking for Kerr and Faraday effects. What about the real parts and negative amounts of real and imaginary parts?